# fullcalendar scheduler set event times to resource

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm a beginner with FullCalendar, and trying to use the vertical resources view from the scheduler add-on. I have some external events that I want to drag onto my resources. The resources are defined like this:

```
    *resources: [
    { id: 1, 
      title: 'shift1',
      businessHours: [
        {
          start: '8:00',
          end: '13:00',
          dow: [1,4,5],
      },
        {
          start: '8:00',
          end: '11:00',
          dow: [3],
        },
        {
          start: '8:00',
          end: '12:00',
          dow: [2],
        },
      ],
      rendering: 'background',
    },
   ],*
```

The behaviour I want is for a dropped event to have it's start and end time set to that of the resource, ie the event duration is the same as the resource. I've searched through the docs and SO, but I can't find a function that works for me (additionally, resourceIds array doesn't work for association to an event, only resourceId). Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: "a dropped event to have it's start and end time set to that of the resource, " ...resources don't have start and end times. I see you've defined some business hours against your resource, which have different times for different days of the week. Are you saying you want the new event to automatically fill the whole space allowed by the business hours for the specific day it was dropped on? If so you'd probably have to fetch the resource object from the calendar, dig into the business hours, and get the details for the correct date.

Comment: There's no built-in function for this, but I'm fairly sure you could make it happen in the way I've described.